# Pass string parameter to asyn task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Hello I'm working with android android and doing some task in a async task. I want to call the async task and pass on string as a parameter. I've search google but with no luck, here is my code to call the async task

```
new warkah_detail().execute(id_warkah);
```

and here is my async task

```
class warkah_detail extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(warkah.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Fetching Details...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args)
    {
        try
        {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_warkah", id_warkah));
            json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_warkah, "POST", params);
```

Those code raise an error like this `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

What is the best way to pass string to async task? I will appreciate any help. Thanks.

[UPDATE]
I had removed the toast, but I still not receive the correct string that pass to async task from the called. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ID : " + id_warkah, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Toast needs to be excuted on the UI Thread. Move it on the `onPostExcuted` or use `runOnUiThread`

your `String` is `args[0]`. You should read the documentation for `varargs`

Comment: oke I had removed that code, but I still can't receive the string that pass to the async task. Any Idea?

Comment: @RadityaKurnianto you have to use the paramter `args` since it is the string passed to doinbackground

Comment: @RadityaKurnianto your string is args[0]. You should read the varargs documentaion

Comment: Sorry my bad, I did some mistakes in the web service that make the received parameter didn't want to work.

Answer (score 1):

Just Remove Below line from your onBackground method.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ID : " + id_warkah, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and put it on onPostExecute method or use runOnUiThread.

Comment: Relace your id_warkah in doinbackground method with args[0].

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by blackbelt you are updating ui on the background thread. Do it onPostExecute(). Or use runOnUiThread

```
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //run on ui thread
      {
           public void run() 
           { 
               // update ui     
           }
      });
```

To use the parameter use it like

```
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_warkah", args[0]));
```

You can check the docs for more info

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You can also pass the parameter to the constructor of the asynctask and use the same.

Answer (score 0):

add new warkah_detail(id_warkah).execute(); instead of new warkah_detail().execute(id_warkah);
and write a constructor for defining your parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
     public class DoSomethingTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

           protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                  // You call your parameter like this
                  String someStringResult = doSomething(params[0]);
                  return someStringResult;
           }

           protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                  doSomethingWithResult(result);
           }
     }
```

And then you call it like this:

```
      new DoSomethingTask().execute("string parameter");
```

And by the way, read more about AsyncTask here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html